# Search nodes within list using node value

Tags: c++, list, iterator, nodes

I am having a hard time coding this (or even figuring out how to code this). I have a list of Nodes.  Every Node contains multiple values, but the only one I care about is a string.

As I am adding nodes to my list, I need to verify the node I am creating doesn't already exist.  If it does exist, I need to access it and modify something within it.  Here is my code so far:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    list<Noeud*> * liste = new list<Noeud*>;
    const string fichierDonnees = "Test01.txt";  


    ifstream fichier;
    fichier.open(fichierDonnees);
    if (!fichier.is_open()) {
        cerr << ConvertirAccents("ERROR OPENING FILE ") << fichierDonnees << endl;

        return -1;
    }else{

    std::ifstream file(fichierDonnees);
    std::string str; 
    int counter=0;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {

        Noeud * temp = new Noeud(str);

    //verify if liste has the node temp;

    }
}

fichier.close();


    _getch(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to traverse the list and check each node. If you find the node then edit it's content. If you don't find it, create a new node in the list with the right content.

Comment: I don't think I was asking someone to write me a list, I already wrote the list and implemented the functions for it. I just don't know how to use an iterator and go through it.  I thought overloading the ==, but that didn't work either

Comment: I have figured out how to use iterators with this:

[code]
   for (std::list<Noeud*>::iterator itera=liste.begin(); it != liste.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it; 
[/code]
I just don'T understand why itera is not a Noeud*, I can't access anything inside of it using -> or .

Comment: itera is an iterator containing a pointer to node.`(*itera)->` will let you access the node's data.

Answer (score 0):

The methods `begin` and `end` don't return the data in a list, they return iterators to the list. Using `*` or `->` operators on an iterator will let you access the data inside. If you have a `std::list<Noeud*>`, the iterators contain `Noeud*`.

```
auto itera = liste.begin(); //itera is std::list<Noeud*>::iterator
*itera; //evaluates to Noeud*
itera->...; //Won't work, pointers don't have members.
(*itera)->...; //Gets pointer from iterator, gets member from pointed to object.
```

You probably don't need a list of pointers, though. Just making a `std::list<Noeud>` usually works. It saves the trouble of having to dereference the iterator first.